# Issue passing model instance to update action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails app I'm trying to create a form for updating model instance attributes with new info and am running into trouble.

When I hit submit on the edit form, the following error is thrown:

```
param is missing or the value is empty: product
```

And here's the code snippet it provides:

```
 # all the attributes that must be submitted for the product to be listed
 def product_params 
   params.require(:product).permit(:name, :price, :description)
 end

 end
```

I think the problem is that the model :product isn't getting passed from the edit form to the update action. Here's the form:

```
<h1>Edit your listing</h1>
<%= form_for edit_item_path(@product), url: {action: "update"} do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.label :name %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :name, :placeholder => "Name yourself" %>
  </div>
  <div><%= f.label :price %><br />
   <%= f.number_field :price, :placeholder => "Name your price" %>
  </div><br />
  <div><%= f.label :description %><br />
   <%= f.text_area :description, :cols => "50", :rows => "10", :placeholder => "Write a few sentences about the item you're listing. Is it in good condition? Are there any accessories included?"%>
  </div>
  <br />
  <%= f.submit "Update listing" %>
 <% end %>
```

Here are the edit and update actions in my products_controller:

```
def edit
 @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @product.update_attributes(product_params)
      format.html {render :action => "show"}
    else
      format.html {render :action => "edit"}
    end
  end
```

end

Finally, my product routes

```
get "/products/new(.:format)" => "products#new", :as => "list_item"
post "/products/create(.:format)" => "products#create"
get "/products(.:format)" => "products#index"
get "/products/:id(.:format)" => "products#show"
get "/products/:id/edit(.:format)" => "products#edit", :as => "edit_item"
post "/products/:id/update(.:format)" => "products#update"
```

So anyone know what the problem is? Am I not passing the right info to the update action? If I'm not, what do I need to do to do it?

Comment: I tried changing the form_for to this: <%= form_for edit_item_path(@product), :url => {:action => :update, :product => @product, :method => :post} do |f| %>

Comment: But now I get: undefined method `permit' for "33":String

Comment: try without passing path to the form. like this: `<%= form_for @product do |f| %>`

Comment: Output the params variable in the `update` method. What that error means is that the params variable doesn't include an index called "product" or the index "product" is empty. It's more than likely a naming issue on the form. 

EDIT: if you really want to know what the form is posting to the controller, you can also inspect the input fields on the form in html to see what the `name` value is.

Answer (score 0):

**`form_for`**

The problem you have is you're using [`form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) without any `object`

> `form_for` generates an appropriate form tag and yields a form builder
>   object that knows the model the form is about. Input fields are
>   created by calling methods defined on the form builder, which means
>   they are able to generate the appropriate names and default values
>   corresponding to the model attributes, as well as convenient IDs, et

`form_for` helpers are primarily designed to give you a way to manage `ActiveRecord` objects:

```
<%= form_for @object do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

--

**Fix**

Everything inside this form block will have to work *with the object* in the `form_for`. As you have only used a `path helper` in your `form_for` method, it's not going to work as you hope.

You'll need to do this:

```
<%= form_for @product, url: {action: "update"} do |f| %>
```

This will ensure your `form_for` populates the object correctly. The error you have basically says your `strong_params` method is expecting this structure:

```
params => {
   "product" => {
       "name" => ____,
       "price" => _____,
       "description" => ______
   }
}
```

As you've not included the `@product` object in your `form_for`, your params hash won't have the `product` key, thus causing your error. The fix is to populate the `form_for` element correctly

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
form_for edit_item_path(@product), url: {action: "update"}
```

with

```
form_for @product
```

which is similar to

```
form_for @product, as: :product, url: product_path(@product), method: :patch do |f|
```